# удаление из localStorage на клик

Tags: javascript

Дано: пользователь кликает на свитчер чтобы добавить в избранное монету. Не получается удалить из localStorage (если пользователь возвращается свитчер в режим off). Пробую команду "localStorage.removeItem("checkedCoins")", но он удаляет все (как clear())

```
function switchClick(event) {

    if(event.target.checked){
        let coinId = event.currentTarget.id;
        const jsonString = localStorage.getItem("checkedCoins")
        if (jsonString) {
                let cryptoCoins = JSON.parse(jsonString)
                cryptoCoins.push({id: coinId});
                let checkedCoinsString = JSON.stringify(cryptoCoins);
                localStorage.setItem("checkedCoins", checkedCoinsString);  
                
                if(cryptoCoins.length > 6 ) {
                    alert("delete")
                }
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem("checkedCoins", JSON.stringify([{id: coinId}]));  
        }
     } else {

       localStorage.removeItem("checkedCoins");
     }
    }
```

Comment: Вам не надо удалять. Вам надо достать значение из localStorage, преобразовать его из строки в массив, отфильтровать массив, исключив ненужные элементы и сохранить полученный результат.

Comment: @PavelNazarian не думаю что понял.

Comment: @PavelNazarian: строка    localStorage.setItem("checkedCoins", JSON.stringify([{id: coinId}]));  каждый раз добавляет новый {id: coinId} , который при повторном клике нужно удалить оттуда же

Comment: извините, был не внимателен

Comment: Похожая проблема https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1548226/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-js-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-jquery-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-localstorage

Answer (score 0):

Сделал с массивом, так по-моему проще, если кроме id ничего не пишете

```
function switchClick(event) {  
  let coinId = +event.currentTarget.id;  
  const cryptoCoins = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("checkedCoins"));    
  if (event.target.checked) {            
    if (cryptoCoins === null) {          
      localStorage.setItem("checkedCoins", JSON.stringify([coinId]));      
      return
    }
    if (cryptoCoins.includes(coinId)) return
    cryptoCoins.push(coinId)    
    localStorage.setItem("checkedCoins",JSON.stringify(cryptoCoins));       
    return
  }
  let filtered_cryptoCoins = cryptoCoins.filter(item => item !== coinId)    
  if (filtered_cryptoCoins.length === 0) {
    localStorage.removeItem("checkedCoins");
    return
  }
  localStorage.setItem("checkedCoins",JSON.stringify(filtered_cryptoCoins));  
}
```