# Как сделать кнопку для удаление на js или jquery данных из массива localstorage?

Tags: javascript, localstorage

При добавлении товара в корзину создается массив products с ключом cart Как сделать так чтобы в колличестве товара отображалось необходимое значение? Эти товары просто добавляются в массив с колличеством один и дублируются.
Не пронимаю как обратиться к этому массиву чтобы происходило удаление по кнопке btn-del?

> Всем заранее спасибо за толковые ответы

> Код внизу взять для примера с этого ресурса

[image: Удаление по клику на кнопку удалить или по кнопке минус]

```
    const deleteBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".btn-del"); // Ищем по класу. sd должно быть уникальным
deleteBtn.forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    let id = event.target.dataset.id; // Берем id
    let itemIndex = data.findIndex(item => +item.id === +id); // Ищем индек элеменда в списке
    if (itemIndex === -1) return;
    data.splice(itemIndex, 1); // Удаляем из списка
    localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(myCart));
    location.reload(); // Обновляем страницу и тогда не будет элемента
    // Или без обновления удаляем через js
  });
});
/*  Создаем объект корзины и сохраняем его в localStorage   */
const myCart = new Cart();

if (localStorage.getItem("cart") == null) {
  localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(myCart));
}

const savedCart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
myCart.products = savedCart.products;
cartNum.textContent = myCart.count;

/* Добавляем товар в корзину */
myCart.products = cardAddArr.forEach((cardAdd) => {
    cardAdd.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const card = e.target.closest(".card");
      const product = new Product(card);
      const savedCart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
      myCart.products = savedCart.products;
      myCart.addProduct(product);
      localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(myCart));
      cartNum.textContent = myCart.count;
    });
});
```

Comment: Из кода: что такое **data** и **myCart*? Вы мутируете значение переменной data, а в хранилище записываете переменной myCart, которую не меняете.... Зачем?

Comment: привет, а можешь написать в телегу? gunsxp